# log4j with liferay and tomcat

Tags: log4j, tomcat6, liferay, liferay-6

I have a Liferay setup on the Tomcat6. I used Log4j initially for portlets/webapps by adding log4j.properties file in the classes folder and log4j.jar file in the web-inf/lib.

Now we have few quartz jobs which are available in the tomcat/lib folder and I want to enable log4j logging for these jobs as well.

For these quartz jobs I have copied same log4j.properties file in the tomcat/lib.

With the new configuration I keep getting the following error:

```
Could not instantiate appender named "JOBS"
A "org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender" is not assignable a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.
The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by ...
```

How to remove this error?

Is there any way I can keep a single log4j.properties file which can be used by both shared/lib as well as portlet/webapps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/%27Could+not+instantiate+appender+named+confluencelog%27+During+Startup) the problem is that you have configured your log4j twice.

My solution would be that you create the logger instance like this

> private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FooBar.class.getName());

and not to have `log4j.properties` under any lib or class folder but having it under a folder named `resources`.

AFAIK this should be a place where the both parts of your application may have access to.

Comment: the 'resources' folder you mention, is a new folder, created under '[Portlet Dir]/docroot/WEB-IF/src' or somewhere else ? Also, do you include log4j.jar, under 'WEB-INF/lib' for each portlet?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/quick-start-maven-spring-example/ tells the properties file location. http://www.liferay.com/web/brett.swaim/blog/-/blogs/using-log4j-to-ensure-each-portlet-has-it-s-own-log-file is a solution for Liferay, somehow different than I have, but tells the location of jars. Having not Liferay, you may put them to WEB-INF/lib, as http://kaushalksinha.blogspot.fi/2009/10/adding-log4j-logging-to-portlet.html suggests. Hope this gave more insight.

Answer (score 1):

Known issue in Liferay: http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-9376

In my case, the problem occurred once I started to use ServiceBuilder services, and added Log4J Logger to one of my ...LocalServiceImpl classes.
Once I removed Log4J logging from there everything got back to norm - exception disappeared.

(I made service methods throw exceptions, and was catching them in a code not related to ServiceBuilder read/generated classes, but it could also be done by changing Log4J logger calls to Liferay's LogUtil calls).

Comment: i am not development in plugin environment so this is could not be the possible solution. however thanks for the answer and this might help me some other time.